# UBER -RIDE REQUEST

Tags: uber-api

Just wanted to ask a question in regards to UBER RIDE REQUEST BUTTON.

So when we integrate with UBER SDK for iOS and Android and use the RIDE WITH UBER button which implicitly launches UBER APP, if installed.

Would we need to send our app for approval to UBER or can we directly push it to app store and play store respectively?

Answer (score 2):

Actually you are using uber sdk and apis which is provided by uber for developers , so need not to approval by UBER you can directly push it to app store and play store.